# Mean & standard deviation

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, means

[image]

for part C),

I'm tempted to think this is a uniform distribution, though not quite sure, as there are two numbers, 50 and 80.

I'm also tempted to think this could be a normal distribution, where I try to build simultaneous equations using the Z-score equation, to solve for mean and standard deviation?

Any ideas how I would go about answering this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the fact that $Pr[A]=Pr[A|B]\cdot Pr[B] + Pr[A|\neg B]\cdot Pr[\neg B]$.
For example 
$$
Pr[C_B=50] = \overbrace{Pr[C_B=50|X\leq 1/2]}^{=1}\cdot Pr[X\leq 1/2] +  \overbrace{Pr[C_B=50|X> 1/2]}^{=0}\cdot Pr[X> 1/2]
$$

Comment: @blaaaaaaa It is best not to use pictures. Instead use mathjax. Here is a tutorial at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference>